# Is this the best way to query an element and its children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to query an element *and* its children to find ID's that begin with a particular string.

```
var foundIDs = containerElement.find('[id^=something]').andSelf().filter('id^=something');
```

The `find()` method only searches descendants so I thought I'd try `andSelf()`.  However, `andSelf()` does not take a selector.  This means that the container element is included regardless of whether it matches the find query or not and I then have to perform a secondary `filter()` on it to remove the container element if it didn't match after all.

I attempted to put `andSelf()` *before* the `find()` but it didn't seem to pick up the container element into the stack.

```
containerElement.andSelf().find('[id^=something]');
```

Is there any better way to achieve what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just off the top of my head (not tested):

```
var foundIDs = containerElement
                     .filter('id^=something')
                     .add(containerElement.find('id^=something'));
```

This isn't that much more efficient than your first effort, but I think it's a little cleaner.

Comment: I guess there's no avoiding having to use the the same selector twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
containerElement.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id^=something]');
```

Comment: Makes sense but my version with a selector in find will reduce the queryset so that the filter will have less to process later on.

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but I'll throw this one out there anyway.

```
var foundIDs = containerElement.wrap('<div>')             // Wrap
                               .parent()                  // Traverse up
                               .find('[id^=something]');  // Perform find

containerElement.unwrap();  // DOM is untouched
```

Because you are unwrapping the `containerElement` before the function is complete, the DOM remains untouched (in case you were wondering).

I verified it with `livequery` plugin, which never detects the new `div`.

If you log the ID (or whatever) of foundIDs, you'll see that the top level is your containerElement (assuming it matched the `.find()` criteria.

```
console.log( foundIDs.attr('id') );  // Log the ID of the root element.
```

---

**EDIT:**

With regard to testing, I performed a 1,000 iteration loop on both versions against a `containerElement` with only 2 nested elements.

I only tested in Safari on Mac.

The accepted answer was around 7 times faster.

If I added 100 nested elements, the gap closed to less that 2 times faster.

<s>Here's the trouble. Both versions returned 0 elements if the `containerElement` didn't match. I'm not sure why this is.</s>

Comment: Clever, but it feels fairly hackish.  I wonder what kind of performance hit that incurs on the stack?

Comment: @Soviut - Good question. I did a little testing. I'll update my answer with my informal, semi-unscientific results. One thing to note is that the accepted answer seems to fail completely if the `containerElement` doesn't match the selector in the `.find()`.

Comment: @Soviut - Disregard my comments about the selectors failing. I was making a bonehead mistake. Although I found a faster method than both answers. I'll post it at the top of my answer.

Comment: You should post it as a second answer to reduce clutter.  That way both can be upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This one has better performance than my other answer, but you lose the chaining ability that your accepted answer offers.

```
    // Do a typical find.
var found = containerElement.find('[class^=something]');

    // Test the containerElement directly,
    //    and push it into the 'found' object if it matches.
if( containerElement.is('[class^=something]') ) found.push(containerElement);
```

Comment: I was trying to do it all in a single query due to how I'm processing 'each()' containerElement that I receive.